# Can SATA III drives work on a PS3?

Tags: ps3

Given that SATA III is backwards compatible and also given that I cannot find a SATA II HDD to buy can I connect a SATA III HDD on my PS3?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sata III to Sata II Port](http://superuser.com/questions/659969/sata-iii-to-sata-ii-port)

Comment: Nope, there's a difference, PS3 is not completely the same. Some HDDs work with everything except the PS3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work. Go ahead.

[Install Hard Disk Drive (12GB PS3 / CECH-4201A)](https://support.us.playstation.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5006/kw/sata)

**Any compatible 5400RPM 2.5" SATA hard disk drive**

> The PS3 has a SATA150 controller. The SATA 3.0 is backwards compatible though.

Unless there is a problem in your mobo's chipset or The PS3 has a problem in the drive's firmware, SATA150 controller. The SATA should auto negotiate the speed properly 3. There should be no need for a jumper0 is backwards compatible though.

http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/266168-32-sata-hard-drive-sata-port